# Configure SSRS delivery extension for invoking a WCF service

Tags: wcf, reporting-services

Have created a custom delivery extension in SQL Server Reporting Services (2008 R2). Within the custom delivery I am making a call to a WCF service. Am not sure where to put the app.config settings for the WCF bindings.

Have tried adding the entire 'system.serviceModel' section into the Reporting Server config file (rsreportserver.config). Have also added the generated app.config file from the custom DLL into the report server's /bin folder. Am still getting the following error though.

> *Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'name of my WCF service' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.*

For now I am changing the code to create the bindings through code but would rather have this config file based. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. I would just create a proxy class of SSRS service objects in code.
B. Then make your own wrapper code for creating a report or getting report info.  I explained this in another question here:

[Programmatically Export SSRS report from sharepoint using ReportService2010.asmx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479144/programmatically-export-ssrs-report-from-sharepoint-using-reportservice2010-asmx/14492191#14492191)

C. Then build a service around those wrapper methods to get your data.